# synclient does not affect my touchpad

Tags: linux, ubuntu, touchpad, dell-xps

After I run

```
synclient MaxTapTime=0
synclient TapButton1=0
synclient TapButton2=0
synclient TapButton3=0
```

my touchpad still executes a click on tap.

Even setting something obvious like `TouchpadOff=1` has no effect on behaviour of the touchpad.

**The question: how do I investigate it further?**

`cat /proc/bus/input/devices` apparently contains two devices named "touchpad": `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad` and `DELL07E6:00 06CB:76AF Touchpad`, can it be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people reported `synclient` not working in Ubuntu 16.04, but I have found another way of disabling tap-to-click:

`xinput set-prop ID "Synaptics Tap Action" 0`
please substitute `ID` with ID of your input device which can be obtained from `xinput list`